# Playlist for "all songs" and organizing alphabetically

Tags: spotify

I am wondering if there is anywhere I can to give suggestions to the developers. I love spotify and I use it daily, at least! There are just a few things that I think would be great improvements. Such as, adding a playlist that includes all songs in every playlist that you, personally make. Or something similar to that. It would also be really helpful and convenient if you had the option to organize playlists alphabetically. Please let me know if there is a place where these ideas can be heard!

Thanks!

Comment: So, the actual question is where you can give suggestions to developers. I think your best bet would be here: https://support.spotify.com/

Comment: I think http://community.spotify.com is the place where feature requests belong.

Comment: Also, you can drag/drop your playlists to re-order and one could write a spotify app to make a meta playlist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great point and this is a problem that we've recognised as well. We're currently working on new ways of creating a discussion between third party developers and the teams that works on the APIs, so please stay tuned and have a look at the [Developer site](https://developer.spotify.com/) from time to time. If you've got feature suggestions for Spotify in general, there's the Spotify Ideas forum. We also monitor [@SpotifyPlatform](http://www.twitter.com/SpotifyPlatform) on Twitter for API related topics.